# C#,asp.net Passwords are not matching after hashing with salt

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash, salt

I have used hashing with salt for password.Before i implemented hashing, i had a stored procedure which used to check textbox value with the value in Database and the code was working fine .After implementing hashing though the passwords are not matching,i checked the hashed value in database and password that i entered and both are same.I looked up in google and some suggested that manually entering value in Database for password will cause an issue.So i created a user registration form and hashed the password there and stored it in the database.Can anyone please guide me as to where i am going wrong.

My loginpagecode:

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;

    namespace taxiservices
    {
        public partial class adminlogin : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            String Salt;
            String Hash;
            String Pwd;
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            public string SaltedHash(string password)
            {
                Salt = "salthashtestsalthashtestsalthashtestsalthashtestsalthashtestsalthashtestsalthashtestsalthashtest";
                Hash = ComputeHash(Salt, password);
                return Hash;

            }

            static string ComputeHash(string salt, string password)
            {
                var saltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
                using (var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, 1000))
                    return Convert.ToBase64String(rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(256));
            }

            public static bool Verify(string salt, string hash, string password)
            {
                return hash == ComputeHash(salt, password);
            }

            protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Session["username"] = username.Text.ToString();
                 Pwd=SaltedHash(password.Text.ToString());
                 Response.Write(Pwd);
                string query;
                string ConnectionStringnew = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringnew))
                {
                    query = "Emplogin";   //stored procedure Name
                    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usename", username.Text.ToString());   //for username 
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password",Pwd);  //for password

                    con.Open();

                    int usercount = (Int32)com.ExecuteScalar();// for taking single value
                    con.Close();
                    if (usercount == 1)  // comparing users from table 
                    {

                        Session["user"] = "valid";

                        Response.Redirect("adminhomepage.aspx");  //for sucsseful login
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        Label2.Text = "Invalid User Name or Password";  //for invalid login
                    }



                }
            }

            protected void username_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Page where user creates a  password:

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace taxiservices
{
    public partial class changepassword : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        String Salt;
        String Hash;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        public string SaltedHash(string password)
        {
            Salt="salthashtestsalthashtestsalthashtestsalthashtestsalthashtestsalthashtestsalthashtestsalthashtest";
            Hash = ComputeHash(Salt, password);
            return Hash;
        }

        static string ComputeHash(string salt, string password)
        {
            var saltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
            using (var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltBytes, 1000))
                return Convert.ToBase64String(rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(256));
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string Pwd = SaltedHash(TextBox2.Text);
            string ConnectionStringn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringn))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Users(Username,Password) VALUES(@User,@password)"))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", TextBox3.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Pwd);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Stored Procedure:

```
    Create  procedure Emplogin
(
@Usename Varchar (20),
@Password varchar (10)
)
as
Begin
Select COUNT(*)from Users where username=@Usename and password=@Password 
End
```

Comment: You're only using 10 characters for the salted password in your sproc -- is that intentional? What is the structure of your `Users` table/

Comment: Isn't it because your @Password parameter in Emplogin procedure is varachar(10). Your hashed password with salt is definitely longer than 10 so what you pass to procedure is probably just first 10 characters, that is why it doesn't match.

Comment: Thank you TZHX,PrzemG i made the changes and it is working fine now.It wasnt intentional i forgot to see that part TZHX

Comment: Just one more thing if you dont mind,this is my code which i want to put in live production for a website i am making ,is it ok,like secure?Is the coding good enough  to be put on a live website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass the details into you `Emplogin` stored procedure, it is only getting the first 10 characters of your salted password (it truncates away the other 246). When it checks this ten-character string against your `Users` database, it doesn't find a match.

You should adjust your `Emplogin` procedure so that the length of the `@Password` variable matches that of the `password` column in your `Users` table.

Comment: Just one more thing if you dont mind,this is my code which i want to put in live production for a website i am making ,is it ok,like secure?Is the coding good enough  to be put on a live website?

Comment: well since you put it that way.. yeah.. it is good enough for a live website... just add a few more tweaks to your coding and everything should be fine..